# Sql Error when running queires file

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to run

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  id int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  favorite_color varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  weight int(5) NOT NULL, 
  favorite_movie varchar(20), 
  state varchar(20), 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I am recieving syntax error near unexpected token `('

Any help appreciated what im doing wrong.

Comment: Is this the only statement you run? I've taken a look at it and it looks okay. Due to the fact that I have no MySQL currently running I can't test it. But I think you run more than just this statement, doesn't you?

Comment: Your statement is fine in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d849f.

Comment: It looks ok. Is there something more to your code and are you sure that these lines are causing syntax error?